How disable prefixing on /dashboard pages with next-intl while still running middleware to avoid unauthorized access
i want to disable route prefixing on /dashboard routes in my nextjs app.
here is my nextjs middleware.ts
const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware(routing);

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const session = (await auth()) as ExtendedSession | null;
  
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  const host = request.headers.get("host");
  const wwwRegex = /^www\./;
  
  const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
  const isAdminPage = pathname.startsWith("/dashboard");
  const isAuthPage = pathname.startsWith("/auth")

  // other logics

  if (isAdminPage) {
    const session = (await auth()) as ExtendedSession | null;
    if (!session || !session.user) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
    }
    if (!session.user.is_admin) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  // protect auth pages when user already logged in
  if (isAuthPage) {
    if (session && session.user) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
  }  

  return intlMiddleware(request);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/",
    "/about-us",
    "/tours",
    "/tours/:path*",
    "/privacy-policy",
    "/terms-and-conditions",
    "/private",
    "/private/:path*",
    "/private-packages",
    "/dashboard",
    "/dashboard/:path*",
    "/auth/login",
    
    '/(en|ru|de)/:path*',

    // match middleware also to an old routes to run 301 redirects
    "/kazbegi-gudauri2",
    "/kaxeti-2",
    "/mtskheta-jvari-gori-uplistsikhe2",
    "/borjomi-rabati-vardzia2",
    "/tbilisi-walking-tour2",
    "/dashbashi-canyon2",
    "/mtskheta-and-jvari-monastery2",
  ],
};


first i try remove /dashboard from matcher but than i wass unable to check user is authorized or not when visiting dashboard pages
second i try to return nextResponse when its dashboard page and return nextMiddleware when its other pages but error iss

Error: No intl context found. Have you configured the provider? See https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/usage/configuration#client-server-components

